# Convert all characters of a string to uppercase, except for some specific characters

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, uppercase, lowercase

I am trying to prevent some characters from being uppercase, while all others has to be.

For an example if I write something in the textbox, it automatically writes all characters uppercase, but everytime I enter the letter "k" it has to be lowercase.

Does any one know a way of achieving this?

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Navn/Name Text Box 


}
```

Comment: I suggest next time adding a 'winforms' tag to the question, so people can know easier if if is WPF, Winforms, ASP.NET, Silverlight, etc.

Comment: Actually, I think the more important part is modifying the string, not writing the result to the textbox. So I would not consider a 'winforms' tag necessary...

Comment: @wkl well that's why I'd say the question is too broad. It asks two questions. The first one being _"How do I selectively change the casing of characters in a string?"_, and the other one being _"How can I change text in a WinForms textbox while the user is typing?"_. I'm also fairly sure both questions have been asked separately as well.

Comment: @ bradbury9 Good point! i am very new to the C# world so everything is not as straight forward for me :D But i will keep that in mind. Happy new year to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `textBox3_TextChanged` event handler you can simply "correct" the text and set it back.
You'll have to remember the cursor position (and selection) so that the user does not get interrupted while typing:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int start = textBox3.SelectionStart;
    int length = textBox3.SelectionLength;
    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.ToUpper().Replace("K", "k");
    textBox3.SelectionStart = start;
    textBox3.SelectionLength = length;
}
```

---

Note: this is for Windows.Forms. I guess for wpf or asp or other ui frameworks the part with the cursor handling will differ.

Answer (score 3):

Here one approach

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = new string(textBox3.Text.Select(x => x == 'k' || x == 'K' ? 'k' : char.ToUpper(x)).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you keep the caret position - where your cursor is.
2. Then, you calculate the new string - I extracted the condition in case it's not just 1 letter.
3. Lastly, you save the new string, and return the caret to its position.

   ```
   private static bool CalculateConditionForLowerCase(string stringLetter)
   {
       return stringLetter.ToLower() == "k";
   }

   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
       {
           return;
       }
       var caretPosition = textBox1.SelectionStart;
       var sb = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (var letter in textBox1.Text)
       {
           var stringLetter = letter.ToString();
           sb.Append(CalculateConditionForLowerCase(stringLetter) ? stringLetter.ToLower() : stringLetter.ToUpper());
       }
       textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
       textBox1.SelectionStart = caretPosition;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to allow the user to enter invalid input, you can use the TextChanged event (other answers) or handle the KeyDown and KeyUp events. Check this link for that other approach.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171537(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, you **don't** use the KeyDown and KeyUp events for input validation. People can change text (drag it around, or cut or paste through the context menu) with the mouse, and there are other ways to modify a control's contents than through the keyboard or mouse.